# How can I make a Talislanta character sheet that will work for Roll20?

Tags: character-sheets, roll20, talislanta

I need a character sheet for the game Talislanta.  It needs to be able to the take Strength value and add it to appropriate skill rolls whenever I click to button for that roll.  I've been trying to find a pre-built character sheet that will work for some time now, but I seem to be coming up short.

Generally, the character sheet would needs to take the character's attributes (such as strength or dexterity) and add them to the skills such as (Stealth or weapon damage modifiers).

Example: If a weapon rolls 1d8 + Strength the sheet applies the character stats and modifiers and adds that to the relevant skill or damage modifier.

Comment: I can't parse your second sentence. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: The character sheet would need to be able to take the characters attributes such as strength or dexterity and add them to the skills such as stealth or weapon damage modifiers. If a weapon rolls 1d8 + strength then the sheet would need to be able to take the character stats once they're put in and add that to the relevant skill modifier or the relevant damage modifier.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  As a Q & A site, we have a particular method that works best.  Please take the [tour] to see how we can best help you.  I have edited your question to frame it as "a problem to solve" or "how do I do this?" rather than a "shopping question" which is how it looked when it was first posted.  With your reply in the comments, what it is that you needed was clearer, so I edited some of that in.  If my edit mistook your intended meaning, please edit the question so that it is clearer using the "edit" button which is right below the tabs rather than a comment.

Comment: Have you asked for help from the Roll20 site itself?

Comment: @MRX, I'm fairly skilled at making R20 character sheets. Email me at my blog, G+, or on R20. I would need a sample character sheet. **R20 does not allow character sheets that "advance characters," only sheets that provide play mechanics.**

Answer (score 2):

In particular you need @{attribute-name-here}
This is dependent on what you named the input the user uses, but when editing

For example:

```
<button roll="/r 1d8+@{dexterity-mod}+@{acrobatics-skill}" />
```

Or for an auto-calculating field such as displaying the total skill-modifier

```
<input type="number" disabled value="@{acrobatics-skill}+@{dexterity-mod}" />
```